# how to make a file that opens the terminal and runs some commands

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need a file that when I click on it opens a command prompt
and runs the following commands

```
cd desktop\discordBOT
node .
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What operating system do you want this to run on? On Unix-derived systems (Linux, MacOS) you probably want to write a shell script, most likely targeting bash. For Windows, a powershell script probably, but someone more familiar with Windows might know better.

Comment: It's for windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a shell script. On windows, this would be a batch file. For you, it would look something like the following:

```
CD C:\Users\foo-\Desktop\discordBOT
node .
PAUSE
```

You could then save this as discord-bot.bat and run the file from your desktop like you want to.

Comment: Thx this works
I need to write CD discordBOT tho 
because The bat file is located on my desktop any ideas how I can specify the whole path instead of only cd discordBOT

Comment: @AikoSchurmann CD to the absolute path of the directory like I did in the post. Don't use a relative path. You'll need to change it a bit to reflect what the actual path is on your PC though.